# react native custom picker set style not working

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I developing a react native project.

I use [react-native-custom-picker](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-custom-picker) but when I try gives a `Custom Picker` style it's not working. my code like this below

```
//.. in CustomPicker.js
<CustomPicker
    placeholder={labelDefault}
    options={options} 
    getLabel={item => item.label}
    optionTemplate={this.renderOption}
    selectedValue={this.props.selectedValue}
    onValueChange={this.onValueChangeCustomPicker}
    textStyle={{color:colors.dark_black,fontSize:25}}--> Here is not work
/>
```

`renderOption()` function like this

```
renderOption(settings) {
    const { item, getLabel } = settings
    return (
      <View style={styles.optionContainer}>
        <View style={styles.innerContainer}>
          <Text style={{ color: colors.dark_black, alignSelf: 'flex-start', fontSize: 24 }} key={item.key}>{item.label}</Text>
        </View>
      </View>
    )
  }
```

I know `Picker` style only support IOS.

What's my fault? Any idea!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I checked source code and documentation if I wanna give style placeholder I should use props for field template like this.

```
<CustomPicker
          fieldTemplateProps={{textStyle:{color:"red",fontSize:22}}}
          placeholder={'Please select your favorite item...'}
          options={options}
          getLabel={item => item.label}
          optionTemplate={this.renderOption}
          headerTemplate={this.renderHeader}
          onValueChange={value => {
            Alert.alert('Selected Item', value ? JSON.stringify(value) : 'No item were selected!')
          }}
        />
```

it's worked in my project 
 [more detail](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-custom-picker#fieldtemplateprops)

Answer (score 0):

can you try this code?

I don't know how you organized `"options,"` but you can't work because you don't have any place to take the factors for `"colors."`

renderOptions:

```js
const options = [ 
...
color: "black",
]
...
renderOption(settings) {
    const { item, getLabel } = settings
    return (
      <View style={styles.optionContainer}>
        <View style={styles.innerContainer}>
          <Text style={{ color: item.color, alignSelf: 'flex-start', fontSize: 25 }} key={item.key}>{item.label}</Text>
        </View>
      </View>
    )
  }

<CustomPicker
    placeholder={labelDefault}
    options={options} 
    getLabel={item => item.label}
    optionTemplate={this.renderOption}
    selectedValue={this.props.selectedValue}
    onValueChange={this.onValueChangeCustomPicker}
/>
```

Comment: this option about my picker each item i can give items style but I didn't give a CustomPicker style it's everytime default same style

Comment: Are you trying to use multiple CustomPickers?